# Create a new column based on values in another column and another table

Tags: python

I have a dataset that shows which community belongs to parent community. It looks like this:

| COMMUNITY | PARENT COMMUNITY |
| --- | --- |
| Community 1 | Community A |
| Community 2 | Community A |
| Community 3 | NaN |
| Community 4 | Community B |
| Community 5 | Community C |

I have a second dataset with raw values, that looks like this:

| ID | COMMUNITY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Community 4 |
| 2 | Community 5 |
| 3 | Community 1 |
| 4 | Community 1 |
| 5 | Community 1 |
| 6 | Community 3 |
| 7 | Community 7 |

I need to transform second dataset using first dataset, so in the end it looks like this:

| ID | COMMUNITY | PARENT COMMUNITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Community 4 | Community B |
| 2 | Community 5 | Community C |
| 3 | Community 1 | Community A |
| 4 | Community 1 | Community A |
| 5 | Community 1 | Community A |
| 6 | Community 3 | Community 3 |
| 7 | Community 7 | NaN |

Also, Please pay attention to PARENT COMMUNITY for Community 3 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pandas you can merge the two dataframes like so:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='COMMUNITY', how='left')
```

If you want to read more you can check out the [documentaion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: it didn't work. it returned: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 747. MiB for an array with shape (97908765,) and data type int64

Comment: in that case the data you are working with may be more than your computer can handle at once, you could try splitting up the second data frame and merging each subset with the first dataframe and then using `pd.concat()` to join up the resulting dataframes

Comment: no, sorry i tried again, it works now. Thank you!